# How to prevent interferencing of inherited property and child-property regarding Domain/Purpose?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm using C# .Net 4.7.2.

Situation:
[image: OOP-Design]

Let's say that we have two domains:
In one we need to ask for the specific type: project.Tasks. Because the caller does not need to know
that Project has Children:ISchedulabe[]:

And in the other domain we need to know the hierarchical tree of the events to schedule them.

Now, with this design, when I want to add a Task to project.Tasks, I have to add Task as ISchedulable to project.Children too. And we carry redundant information, kind of.

Another approach I've tried is to override the getter of Children in Project:

```
public override List<ISchedulable> Children
{
    get => Tasks.Cast<ISchedulable>().ToList();
}
```

But that means, that I always cast the entire List and! that I cannot iterate over the List because it is "modified" at every iteration.

And a third approach is, that I build the hierarchical structure just when I need it. I know that all types inherit from ISchedulable so I can build the hierarchy and set the parent and the children. But than again the object would have parent/children as null until we calculate them.

What am I missing? Do someone has an idea for a design in which the domains are seperated?

Comment: Don't you have a base class with inherited children?  So you can put minimal information into a base class and the hierarchical tree in the inherited class.

Comment: @jdweng: A base class for whom?

Comment: An inherited class (child) has more properties than the base class (parent).  So you want the parent to have a limited number of properties and the child to have the detailed properties.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Evans in his masterwork Domain Driven Design: The heart of software suggestes to draw the bounded context within a domain. What i want to say is that if you already know that a concept (in this case ISchedulable, Project, Task and ToDo) is used for different purposes you would probably need to have duplicate them.

Anyway, I seem to understand that a Project cannot have ToDos or Projects as children, a Task cannot have Projects or Todos as children and ToDos cannot have children at all.
Let's take a look at this approach, where I use both Composite and Visitor pattern:

```
public interface ISchedulable {
    ISchedulable Parent {get;set;}
    IEnumerable<ISchedulable> Children {get;} //this collection is readonly
    DateTime Start {get; set; }
    DateTime End {get; set; }
    T AcceptVisitor<T>(ISchedulableVisitor<T> visitor);
}
public interface ISchedulableVisitor<T> {
    T Visit(Project p);
    T Visit(Task t);
    T Visit(ToDo td);
}
public abstract class SchedulableBase : ISchedulable {
    public ISchedulable Parent {get;set;}
    public abstract IEnumerable<ISchedulable> Children {get;} //this collection is readonly
    public DateTime Start {get; set; }
    public DateTime End {get; set; }
    public abstract T AcceptVisitor<T>(ISchedulableVisitor<T> visitor);
}    

public class Project : SchedulableBase {
    public override IEnumerable<ISchedulable> Children => Tasks.Cast<ISchedulable>();
    private readonly List<Task> _tasks = new List<Task>();
    public IEnumerable<Task> Tasks => _tasks;
    public void AddTask(Task t) {
       t.Parent = this;
       _tasks.Add(t);
    } 
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public override T AcceptVisitor<T>(ISchedulableVisitor<T> visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}    

public class Task : SchedulableBase {
    public override IEnumerable<ISchedulable> Children => ToDos.Cast<ISchedulable>(); 
    private readonly List<ToDo> _todos = new List<ToDo>();
    public IEnumerable<ToDo> ToDos => _todos;
    public void AddToDo(ToDo t) {
       t.Parent = this;
       _todos.Add(t);
    }

    public Employee Head {get;set;}
    public override T AcceptVisitor<T>(ISchedulableVisitor<T> visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}

public class ToDo : SchedulableBase {
    public override IEnumerable<ISchedulable> Children => Enumerable.Empty<ISchedulable>();
    public object Whatever {get;set;}
    public override T AcceptVisitor<T>(ISchedulableVisitor<T> visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}
```

Now, if you want to add a Task to a Project, you need to know that the project is of type Project and that the Task is of type Task.

when you need to perform some logic depending on the type of the schedulables, you can use the visitor:

```
public class ToDosCounter : ISchedulableVisitor<int> {
     public int Visit(Project p) {
         int ris = 0;
         foreach (Task t in p.Tasks) {
              ris += t.AcceptVisitor(this);
         }
         return ris;
      }
      public int Visit(Task t) {
         int ris = 0;
         foreach(ToDo td in t.ToDos) {
              ris+=td.AcceptVisitor(this);
         }
         return ris;
      }
      public int Visit(ToDo td) {
         return 1;
      }
 }
```

And the caller doesn't need to know on which type is calling the logic:

```
      public void DoLogic(ISchedulable s) {
           var numberOfTodos = s.AcceptVisitor(new ToDoCounter());
           ///
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort to write the code down. I like the composite pattern idea, which I am implementing right now. And until now I didn't break something, so it looks good =)